# What is the word for oddly matched meal items

Tags: synonyms

For example if I have a burger and soup, or spaghetti and milk. Almost like a potluck or a pitch-in, but less on purpose.

Comment: I recommend that you add the 'single-word-request' tag to your question  '*Use this tag for questions that are about finding a single word to fit a meaning. Describe the word's intended meaning, its connotation (is it laudatory or derogatory?), and/or its context in as much detail as you can. Questions that show no research are likely to be closed. **It's also a good idea to show users how this single word fits in a sentence**.*' and edit your question to follow the tag requirements.

Comment: Where I hail from. (New York, USA) there are so many different cultures and tastes that it's quite common to see someone eating a combination of foods that would disgust the next person. Since there are no actual "laws" for most of us, we have adopted the term of the most familiar culture that does have rules. "Melange" is good - if you need a single word - but, if the intention is to convey disapproval, you'd say something like, "That meal is not Kosher."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not too much of a mixed metaphor in this instance,

> **smorgasbord**
>
> 1:  a luncheon or supper buffet offering a variety of foods and dishes
>   (as hors d'oeuvres, hot and cold meats, smoked and pickled fish,
>   cheeses, salads, and relishes)
>
> 2:  an often large heterogeneous mixture, melange

[[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smorgasbord)] seems a reasonable fit.

As hinted, **melange** / mélange is another possibility.

Comment: The closest I could find was "collation." Melange seems a good fit, but I don't think anyone I know would know the meaning

Comment: @Lourens Would that make three incompatible items (say a burger, soup, and spaghetti) a melange a trois?

Comment: @deadrat hahahaha, definitely. Is this even english any more?

Comment: ... Something between a red herring and a Jackson Pollock.

Comment: A smorgasbord is a large variety of dishes served together, but is made of dishes that wouldn't normally be put together? The OP says "Almost like a potluck or a pitch-in, but less on purpose": to my mind, a smorgasbord would be a deliberate collection of dishes, maybe even more so than a potluck. E.g. a friend of mine likes to eat toast with marmalade & fried eggs at the same time — I thought the OP was looking for a term for something like that (apart from disgusting!), though they have accepted this answer, so not sure anymore!

Comment: @anotherdave That's why I included definition (2) and mentioned the problem with this metaphorical usage here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah OK, see what you mean! I'd agree with your opening line though — for me, when applied to food, the subject feels too close to home of meaning #1 for a metaphorical usage of meaning #2.

Comment: It's very confusing that the OP has accepted this because I really can't see that smorgasbord could be used by the OP and automatically be understood to be talking about 'mismatched' food combinations. if I was invited to partake of a smorgasbord I'd be expecting breads, cheeses, meats and pickled stuff which were all tried and tested combinations, rather than spaghetti and milk. On that basis I'm reluctantly voting the answer down.